# Windows10: How do I uninstall OneDrive app via powershell?

Tags: windows, windows-10

The app is listed when viewing Windows Settings => Apps but when I displayed all the packages in my system (new install) using

```
get-appxpackage
```

I cannot see it. But perhaps it's listed with an alias of sorts?

Thanks

Comment: untested: https://github.com/TERRAOperative/OneDrive-Uninstaller

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a complete PS1 script to remove all traces of if:

```
Import-Module -DisableNameChecking $PSScriptRoot\..\lib\force-mkdir.psm1
Import-Module -DisableNameChecking $PSScriptRoot\..\lib\take-own.psm1

echo "73 OneDrive process and explorer"
taskkill.exe /F /IM "OneDrive.exe"
taskkill.exe /F /IM "explorer.exe"

echo "Remove OneDrive"
if (Test-Path "$env:systemroot\System32\OneDriveSetup.exe") {
    & "$env:systemroot\System32\OneDriveSetup.exe" /uninstall
}
if (Test-Path "$env:systemroot\SysWOW64\OneDriveSetup.exe") {
    & "$env:systemroot\SysWOW64\OneDriveSetup.exe" /uninstall
}

echo "Disable OneDrive via Group Policies"
force-mkdir "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\OneDrive"
sp "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\OneDrive" "DisableFileSyncNGSC" 1

echo "Removing OneDrive leftovers trash"
rm -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue "$env:localappdata\Microsoft\OneDrive"
rm -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue "$env:programdata\Microsoft OneDrive"
rm -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue "C:\OneDriveTemp"

echo "Remove Onedrive from explorer sidebar"
New-PSDrive -PSProvider "Registry" -Root "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT" -Name "HKCR"
mkdir -Force "HKCR:\CLSID\{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}"
sp "HKCR:\CLSID\{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}" "System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree" 0
mkdir -Force "HKCR:\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}"
sp "HKCR:\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}" "System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree" 0
Remove-PSDrive "HKCR"

echo "Removing run option for new users"
reg load "hku\Default" "C:\Users\Default\NTUSER.DAT"
reg delete "HKEY_USERS\Default\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "OneDriveSetup" /f
reg unload "hku\Default"

echo "Removing startmenu junk entry"
rm -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue "$env:userprofile\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\OneDrive.lnk"

echo "Restarting explorer..."
start "explorer.exe"

echo "Wait for EX reload.."
sleep 15

echo "Removing additional OneDrive leftovers"
foreach ($item in (ls "$env:WinDir\WinSxS\*onedrive*")) {
    Takeown-Folder $item.FullName
    rm -Recurse -Force $item.FullName
}
```

If you want the easy uninstall way, Open cmd in admin mode, type in `taskkill /f /im OneDrive.exe`  to terminate OneDrive process.

Then type in either `%SystemRoot%\System32\OneDriveSetup.exe /uninstall` if you’re using 32-bit or `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\OneDriveSetup.exe /uninstall` if you’re using 64-bit Windows 10.

Update:
Function for forced directory creation:

```
function force-mkdir($path) {
if (!(Test-Path $path)) {
    #Write-Host "-- Creating full path to: " $path -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor DarkGreen
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $path
}}
```

Registry ownership assimilation:

```
    function Takeown-Registry($key) {
    # TODO does not work for all root keys yet
    switch ($key.split('\')[0]) {
        "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT" {
            $reg = [Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::ClassesRoot
            $key = $key.substring(18)
        }
        "HKEY_CURRENT_USER" {
            $reg = [Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::CurrentUser
            $key = $key.substring(18)
        }
        "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" {
            $reg = [Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::LocalMachine
            $key = $key.substring(19)
        }
    }

    # get administraor group
    $admins = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier("S-1-5-32-544")
    $admins = $admins.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])

    # set owner
    $key = $reg.OpenSubKey($key, "ReadWriteSubTree", "TakeOwnership")
    $acl = $key.GetAccessControl()
    $acl.SetOwner($admins)
    $key.SetAccessControl($acl)

    # set FullControl
    $acl = $key.GetAccessControl()
    $rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule($admins, "FullControl", "Allow")
    $acl.SetAccessRule($rule)
    $key.SetAccessControl($acl)
}

function Takeown-File($path) {
    takeown.exe /A /F $path
    $acl = Get-Acl $path

    # get administraor group
    $admins = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier("S-1-5-32-544")
    $admins = $admins.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])

    # add NT Authority\SYSTEM
    $rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($admins, "FullControl", "None", "None", "Allow")
    $acl.AddAccessRule($rule)

    Set-Acl -Path $path -AclObject $acl
}

function Takeown-Folder($path) {
    Takeown-File $path
    foreach ($item in Get-ChildItem $path) {
        if (Test-Path $item -PathType Container) {
            Takeown-Folder $item.FullName
        } else {
            Takeown-File $item.FullName
        }
    }
}

function Elevate-Privileges {
    param($Privilege)
    $Definition = @"
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    public class AdjPriv {
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
            internal static extern bool AdjustTokenPrivileges(IntPtr htok, bool disall, ref TokPriv1Luid newst, int len, IntPtr prev, IntPtr rele);
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
            internal static extern bool OpenProcessToken(IntPtr h, int acc, ref IntPtr phtok);
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            internal static extern bool LookupPrivilegeValue(string host, string name, ref long pluid);
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
            internal struct TokPriv1Luid {
                public int Count;
                public long Luid;
                public int Attr;
            }
        internal const int SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED = 0x00000002;
        internal const int TOKEN_QUERY = 0x00000008;
        internal const int TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = 0x00000020;
        public static bool EnablePrivilege(long processHandle, string privilege) {
            bool retVal;
            TokPriv1Luid tp;
            IntPtr hproc = new IntPtr(processHandle);
            IntPtr htok = IntPtr.Zero;
            retVal = OpenProcessToken(hproc, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, ref htok);
            tp.Count = 1;
            tp.Luid = 0;
            tp.Attr = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
            retVal = LookupPrivilegeValue(null, privilege, ref tp.Luid);
            retVal = AdjustTokenPrivileges(htok, false, ref tp, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            return retVal;
        }
    }
"@
    $ProcessHandle = (Get-Process -id $pid).Handle
    $type = Add-Type $definition -PassThru
    $type[0]::EnablePrivilege($processHandle, $Privilege)
}
```

Comment: This script imports `force-mkdir.psm1` and `take-own.psm1`, but you don't show where to get those.

Comment: Added the scripts explicitly.

Answer (score 6):

I just know a CMD method to uninstall OneDrive:

1. Open Command Prompt as Administrator
2. Type in `taskkill /f /im OneDrive.exe`  to terminate any OneDrive processes and hit Enter.
3. Type in `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\OneDriveSetup.exe /uninstall` if you’re using 64-bit Windows 10 and hit Enter.

You won’t see a confirmation dialog or progress bar when you do this, but if you try searching for OneDrive, the app will no longer be found. Of course, your OneDrive folder and files, however, will still be available.

Answer (score 6):

Here's Origami's CMD method in PowerShell:

```
ps onedrive | Stop-Process -Force
start-process "$env:windir\SysWOW64\OneDriveSetup.exe" "/uninstall"
```

Answer (score -1):

OneDrive is built into Windows 10, so you can’t uninstall it like an app. However, you can hide it and stop syncing OneDrive files to your PC. To do so, follow the steps in this link.

https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Turn-off-or-uninstall-OneDrive-f32a17ce-3336-40fe-9c38-6efb09f944b0?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: Please provide detailed instructions within the body of your answer

Comment: This is incorrect.  You can uninstall the app through the Win10 settings or through the old-school Control Panel.  It's not "built in" so much as "pre-installed".  Additionally, it is possible to remove a lot of the built in garbage that MS decided to have in Windows 10 using powershell to bludgeon Win10 into acting like you actually have some control over what apps you want on your system.